# Modalverb + Partizip 2 + sein/haben

Tags: modal-verb

What's the difference between these two sentences:

> Er hat den Verbrecher erhängen sollen.
>
> Er **soll** den Verbrecher **erhängt haben**.

There's also this sentence:

> Die Waffe **muss** mir aus der Tasche **gefallen sein**.

Can you guys please explain to me the grammar behind this weird conjugation?

Comment: @Rha I thought verbs used with sein always turned into passive, is that not true @Rha?

Comment: No, this is wrong. For example: *Ich bin gelaufen* - no passive here, it's just the perfect. Perfect and *Zustandspassiv* may look the same, it depends on the verb which is which. For example, *Das Auto ist zerstört* is *Zustandspassiv* becaue *zerstören*, unlike *laufen*, is transitive.

Comment: He should have hung the criminal vs. He is said to have hung the criminal.

Comment: Could you please put a little more effort in asking a question?

Comment: I don't think OP could have done much, I tried searching their question and I didn't find any site describing this exact issue @Olafant

Answer (score 2):

These aren't (very) weird, just examples of what happens when you use a modal verb with the perfect past. I'll start with the third sentence. The basic form (present indicative) is:

> *Die Waffe fällt mir aus der Tasche.*
> "The weapon falls out of my pocket."

There is some subtlety here around using *mir ... der Tasche* instead of *meiner Tasche*, but that's a topic for another question. The auxiliary verb for *fallen* is *sein*, so to form the perfect past replace the finite verb with the conjugated form of *sein*, and place the past participle (Partizip II) of the original verb at the end:

> *Die Waffe ist mir aus der Tasche gefallen.*
> "The weapon has fallen out of my pocket."

On top of that, apply the modal verb *müssen*. As with the English "must", when *müssen* is used with the perfect past, the meaning is usually that you are drawing some kind of conclusion from observable facts. The weapon is on the ground instead of where you expected to be, so ...:

> *Die Waffe muss mir aus der Tasche gefallen sein.*
> "The weapon must have fallen out of my pocket."

In this case the conjugated form of *müssen* replaces the verb (now *ist*) and the infinitive of the verb (*sein*) is placed at the end.

Something similar happens in the second sentence. The auxiliary verb for *erhängen* is *haben* (as it is for all transitive verbs). The modal verb in this case is *sollen*, which has a number of meanings, but from context what is meant is that the event is rumored to happen, or that it's common knowledge that it happens. The sequence is:

> *Er erhängt den Verbrecher.*
> "He hangs the criminal."
> *Er hat den Verbrecher erhängt.*
> "He has hanged the criminal."
> *Er soll den Verbrecher erhängt haben.*
> "He is said to have hanged the criminal."

The first sentence is also similar except that order of operations is reversed and there is a difference in meaning as a result. In this case *sollen* probably means something like *should* or *is supposed to*, but it's hard to tell for sure since there isn't much context given. First, the present tense using *sollen*:

> *Er soll den Verbrecher erhängen.*
> "He should hang the criminal."

The auxiliary verb of *sollen* is *haben*. The past participle of *sollen* is *gesollt*, but this time there *is* a kind of weird exception. When a past participle would be placed after an infinitive, then the participle is replaced by another infinitive. (I've heard this called the "double infinitive rule" but I don't know if there's an official name for it.) So instead of putting *gesollt* at the end, *sollen* is placed there instead. The result is:

> *Er hat den Verbrecher erhängen sollen.*
> "He was supposed to hang the criminal."

PS. Another bit of weirdness here is that the past participle of *erhängen* is *erhängt*. I would have expected it to be *erhangen*, but apparently that's "colloquial". That's a topic for yet another question though.

Comment: I don’t think that “erhangen” exists, however both “gehangen” and “gehängt” exist and should be distinguished: https://www.dwds.de/wb/h%C3%A4ngen And just to complicate things, there is also “gehenkt” https://www.dwds.de/wb/henken

Comment: @Carsten S: Thanks. I only had *gehangen* in my notes. English Wiktionary says of *erhangen:* "The verb is predominantly weak. Strong forms are now chiefly colloquial.' There is a "hanged"/"hung" distinction in English, but I don't know how many people pay attention to it.

Comment: I feel like this answer raised more questions than it did answer

Comment: @RDBury, the distinction is not made consistently by all German speakers, including me. Many of the irregular English verb forms that I have learned in school seem endangered anyway. Who still uses “shone”?

Comment: @Carsten S: Niel Young: "And the water shone like diamonds in the dew" (from "Thrasher"). But yes, "shone" is mostly limited to poetry and lyrics now days. I think it's a general rule that when you learn a foreign language in school it's the version used by very polite elderly people 50 to 100 years ago. At least that's the impression I've gotten talking with people who learned English in school.

Comment: @RDBury What's the difference between "Die Waffe fiel mir aus der Tasche" AND "Die Waffe fiel aus meiner Tasche" AND "Die Waffe fiel aus meiner Tasche heraus"???

Comment: @KeN SmilePachI: That seems like it should be the topic of another question -- not something you can answer in a comment. I'm probably not the best person to ask anyway.